# How to set parameters in a get request from reactJS

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, get

Maybe its a very newbie question for here but i spend a lot of time to see a good approach for doing this and i didn't find convenient answer. I am trying to make a simple call to a rest api and i want to pass a value with the GET request appended to the string. like url/foo where foo is the parameter. I have a query variable that i want to append to the end of the url string for the get request. Thank you in advance.

```
class About extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            filteredItems: [],
            user: {},
            query: '' <-- query variable to be appended to the end of the get request
        };

    }



    componentDidMount() {

        fetch(`'myurl/${this.state.query}'`) <-- i want to append the variable at the end of the string ??
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    this.setState({
                        products: result,
                        filteredItems: result
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    queryChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({query: evt.target.value}) <-- update the variable state from an event
    }
```

Comment: Is what you're using there not working? Template strings look like a good way of doing this.

Comment: Actually when i submit the form i don't know how to invoke componentDidMount() thats my problem so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the extra quotations (`'`) in `'myurl/${this.state.query}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
let query = {id:1};
let url = 'https:example.com//xyz.com/search?' + query;

 fetch(url)
```

Comment: Ok when i try url + query attached in the end of the string i get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data i tried to fetch the data hardcoded and i don't get the json parse error.. also with removing the commas from the url the error is the same its something else

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the help my problem is elsewhere but the answer from Avinash Mahlawat and from ehutchllew are working perfectly for the asked question.

Comment: It's my pleasure and i hope you do the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass param without using `` or $ also,In componentDidMount()

```
   componentDidMount() {
        let query = this.state.query;
        fetch('myurl/'+query)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    this.setState({
                        products: result,
                        filteredItems: result
                    });
                }
            )
    }
```

Comment: Okay i also found what my mistake was i was expecting when i post the form  componentDidMount() {} to be fired with the proper url + query appended but it dosen't. It worked for me to fetch the data inside a onClick event of button. In other words i move the logic from componentDidMount() into a onClick function and it works fine.

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to upvote it. Done. Thank you again